# PHP Getting Image URL from wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress widgets I have a "Image" widget. It has:

- Title
- The image you uploaded or want to upload
- The size
- The link
- The link text

Now I want to know, is there a hook or something i can use to grab that "link" from the saved widget? See below. On the 4th line I want to display the link from that image widget here where it says THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO GET THAT LINK HERE.

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )    
    register_sidebar(array(    
        'name' => 'Other Serviecs Page Widget',    
        'before_widget' => '<a href="THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO GET THAT LINK HERE"><div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                    <div class="add-box-main"> ',    
        'after_widget' => '<div class="box-bottom"> </div>                                           
                                    </div>
                                </div>',    
        'before_title' => '<div class="box-heading"> <img src="../wp-content/uploads/2014/10/OS-LOGO.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""><h2>',    
        'after_title' => '</h2></div>',  
));   


if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )    
    register_sidebar(array(    
        'name' => 'Other Serviecs Page Bottom Widget',    
        'before_widget' => '</a>',    
        'after_widget' => '',    
        'before_title' => '<h1 class="hide">',    
        'after_title' => '</h1>',    
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Widget settings are stored in the options table. You can get the content of an option field with `get_option()`. Replace `MY_WIDGET` with the actual ID of your widget:

```
$widget = get_option( 'widget_MY_WIDGET' );
```

Use `print_r` to inspect the returned value (`false` if option does not exist) and get an idea of how to grab the desired value:

```
print_r( $widget );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at wp_get_attachment_url in the Wordpress codex? Here's the link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url

That will return the full path to the image file assuming that there's a loop running.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I tried this:

before_widget' => '<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url( $id ).'">